# Enviando Email PHP

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código :

```
$para      = $_REQUEST['EMAIL'];
$titulo    = 'El título probando';
$mensaje   = 'es de prueba';
$cabeceras = 'From: Equipo blabla' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: ese' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($para, $titulo, $mensaje, $cabeceras);
```

Y tengo el siguiente error :

```
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoLuifer01\Controller.php on line 30
```

He ido al php.ini y tengo:

```
SMTP=localhost
smtp_port=25
mail.add_x_header=On
```

Estoy probando , no estoy con ningún servidor y eso de SMTP y protocolos no entiendo mucho ...

Comment: Necesitas instalar un servidor de correo en local y/o configurarlo en PHP.ini.

Comment: Con JSP le pongo un correo y una contraseña para que el JSP envíe un email desde la dirección que le meto por código, No hay lo mismo en PHP ??

Comment: Con xampp hay una herramienta para emular el envio de email, se encuentra en c:\xampp\mailtodisk, tambien en la ayuda de xamp viene un ejemplo de configuración: localhost/dashboard/docs/send-mail.html